# Dropdown menu not expanding Safari window

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, safari

I have a dropdown menu made dynamically of divs across the top of the web page. If one of the dropdowns gets large enough that it needs to expand the browser window then it doesn't expand the Safari window. This works fine in both internet explorer and firefox. I have tried several css settings but can't seem to come up with the solution. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

So here is the original css when the sub-menu is put on the page:

```
.sub_menu {
display:none;
z-index: 2;
margin-left:5px;
padding:10px;
width: 140px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 120px;
background: #F4F4F4;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4, #EEEEEE);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#F4F4F4), to(#EEEEEE));
border: solid 1px #b4b4b4;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, .3);
}
```

The display:none keeps the sub-menus from displaying

Then I have javascript that fires on a hover:

```
#menu li:hover > ul, #menu li.hover > ul {
display: block;
}
```

This displays the sub-menu but doesn't expand the Safari browser window in the case that this menu gets too large vertically for the screen

Comment: Please post some code or an example if you'd like help.

Comment: I will also add that if I do a {display: block;} on page load css then the Safari page expands correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up doing somewhat of a workaround to get this to work. I set the CSS to have display:block; but visibility:hidden; when loading the page. Then on hover the CSS would change visibility to visible. This worked with all browsers tested - IE, Firefox, Chrome and Safari. Unfortunately this workaround doesn't dynamically re-size the browser window when the DIV visibility changes.